# Problem with getting calculations of an array inside of an array done right

Tags: c++, arrays, function

Using the formula in the pic, I need to write a program that allows the user to calculate sin(x), cos(x), tan(x). The user should enter the angle in degrees, and then the program should transform it into radians before performing the three requested calculations. For each requested calculation (i.e., sin(x), cos(x), tan(x)), I only need to calculate the first 15 terms of the series.

The problem seems to be in the arrays of the last block in the code, it keeps returning wrong results of the tan(x) series; how can I fix it?

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

//create a function to convert angles from degrees to radian
  double convertToRadian(double deg)
{     //formula : radian = (degree * pi)/180
   const double pi = 3.14159265359; //declaring pi's value as a constant
   return (deg * (pi / 180)); //returning the radian value
}

//create a function to calculate the exponent/power
double power(double base, unsigned int exp)
{
   double result = 1;
   for(int i = 0; i < exp; i++){
    result = result * base;
 }
 return result;
 }

 //create a function to get the factorial of a value 
 double factorial(int fac)
 {
   if(fac > 1)
      return fac * factorial(fac - 1);
    else
    return 1;
    }

   //create a function to print out arrays as we will use it to print the terms in the series
      void printTerms(double terms[15])
       { for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
         {
           cout<<terms[i]<<endl;
          }
          }


     int main()
       {
           double degree; //declare the variables used in the program
          double valueOfCos, valueOfSin, valueOfTan;  //declare variables for terms of each function
            cout << "Enter angle (x) in degrees: " << endl; //prompt for user to enter angle in deg
            cin >> degree;
               double radian = convertToRadian(degree); //first, converting from degrees to radian

         //make an array for the first 15 terms of cos(x):
         double cos[15];
        //make a loop to insert values in the array
        for (int n = 0; n < 15; n++)
       { //type the maclaurin series formula for cos(x):
        valueOfCos = (( power(-1 , n)) / (factorial(2*n))) * (power(radian, (2*n)));
          cos[n] = valueOfCos;
        }
           //print out the first 15 terms of cos(x) in the maclaurin series:
          cout << "cos(x)= ";
           printTerms (cos);

          //make an array for the first 15 terms of sin(x):
            double sin[15];
           for (int n = 0; n < 15; n++)
           {
             valueOfSin = ((power(-1 , n)) / (factorial((2*n + 1)))) * (power(radian, (2*n + 1)));
             sin[n] = valueOfSin;
            }
              cout << "sin(x)= ";
              printTerms (sin);

              double tan[15];
                for (int n = 0; n < 15; n++)
                     {   double bernoulli[15] = {(1/6), (-1/30),(1/42), (-1/30), (5/66), (-691/2730), 
              (7/6), (-3617/510), (43867/798), (-174611/330), (854513/138), (-236364091/2730), 
             (8553103/6),(-23749461029/870),(8615841276005/14322) };
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        double firstNum = 0, secondNum = 0 , thirdNum = 0 , denominator = 0;
        firstNum = power(-1 , n);
        secondNum = power(2 , 2*n + 2);
        thirdNum = ((secondNum) - 1);
        denominator = factorial(2*n + 2);
        valueOfTan = ((firstNum * secondNum * thirdNum * (bernoulli[i])) / denominator) * 
               (power(radian, 2*n + 1));
           tan [n] = valueOfTan;
        }
    }
     cout << "tan(x)= ";
     printTerms (tan);
 
         return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to *debug* your program? For example by using a *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: To help with debugging, first of all try to reindent your code. Consistent indentation is crucial for humans to be able to read the code. I also recommend that you break up larger expressions into smaller, saving results in temporary variables. That makes it easier to see intermediate results. Also try to scale back your code, so it becomes simpler and easier to test and debug. And of course build with extra warnings enabled, and treat all warnings as errors.

Comment: And lastly a hint about your problems: The result of e.g. `1/6` is ***zero***. That's because division between two integer values (like `1` and `6`) gives an integer result. All values used to initialize the `bernoulli` array suffer from this problem. If you looked at this array in a debugger then this problem would have been obvious.

Answer (score 2):

This loop :  `for (int n = 0; n < 15; n++)` is not running or entire expression. You'll need to correct something like this :

```
double bernoulli[15] = {(1/6), (-1/30),(1/42), (-1/30), (5/66), (-691/2730),(7/6), (-3617/510), (43867/798), (-174611/330), (854513/138), (-236364091/2730),(8553103/6),(-23749461029/870),(8615841276005/14322) };
for (int n = 0; n < 15; n++){
 double firstNum = 0, secondNum = 0 , thirdNum = 0 , denominator = 0;
 firstNum = power(-1 , n);
 secondNum = power(2 , 2*n + 2);
 thirdNum = ((secondNum) - 1);
 denominator = factorial(2*n + 2);
 valueOfTan = ((firstNum * secondNum * thirdNum * (bernoulli[n])) / denominator) * (power(radian, 2*n + 1));
               tan [n] = valueOfTan;
            }
    }
```

Comment: i manually calculated the bernoulli numbers used in the problem, B2, B4, B5 ..... B30; and put them in an array as their values are **constants** in the problem

Comment: Modified as per this info

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly calculating the tan value.

In `valueOfTan = ((firstNum * secondNum * thirdNum * (bernoulli[i])) / denominator) * (power(radian, 2 * n + 1));`

Instead of bernoulli[i], you need to have bernoulli[2*i+2] as per the formulae.

And one more suggestion please pull the  `double bernoulli[15] = {(1/6), (-1/30),(1/42), (-1/30), (5/66), (-691/2730),  (7/6), (-3617/510), (43867/798), (-174611/330), (854513/138), (-236364091/2730),  (8553103/6),(-23749461029/870),(8615841276005/14322)` array initialization out of the for loop, as it's constant you don't need to initialize it every time unnecessarily. It will increase your code runtime

Comment: i manually calculated the bernoulli numbers used in the problem, B2, B4, B5 ..... B30; and put them in an array as their values are constants in the problem

Comment: Tell me one thing so in the formulae, B{2*n+2} for n = 1 represents what from the array ?? Is it not bernoulli[4]

Comment: the bernoulli number is a constant b0 = 1, b2 = (1/6) and so on, i only needed the first 15 terms for tan so i calculated their (b2, b4, b6) the only ones i needed and put them in an array, im starting from when n = 0. till n =14 , 15 terms only

Comment: broooo, you are using two loops for tan. You don't need it.Just runone loop only, remove that loop with iand instead of bernoullie[i] use bernoulie[n]

Comment: Can you please share those guidelines with me. I can see that you are always editing my posts only. Please share the references, I will go through them

Comment: The [canonical advice is here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions). Here is a [question about "hope this helps"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258187/is-it-ok-to-write-hope-that-helps-or-why-is-my-answer-being-edited), which has pretty much the same answer. There are more questions (with the same advice again) in the sidebar.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "always editing my posts only". I have edited over 93,000 posts, and I've probably edited some 10-20 posts of yours. Clearly I am not just editing your work, by a long margin.

Comment: Hi @halfer, Sorry, if you felt rude. I wasn't saying it that way. I meant to ask what is wrong in my posts that it requires editing, I just want to improve it further

Comment: Your posts seem fine to me generally. I can't always comment on the technical content, as you'll know many technologies that I am unfamiliar with. But, as a rule, we try to aim for technical writing - which means that our material is more like documentation than a chat-room. This makes material easier to read and understand. If you can apply that suggestion to your future posts, you may even find they get upvotes more easily, as people will have less to read to get the same meaning.

Comment: To give you an idea of the material that is not technical writing, I sometimes post this advice (for questions, though it kind of applies to answers too): _Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._

Comment: (Incidentally, I didn't take your question as a rudeness - I just didn't understand it. I don't mind answering meta-questions here `:=)`).